# A couple unrelated questions from Jech's "Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We are taking a course in set theory and the book we are working with is Jech's *Set Theory*. This is not my first course in set theory. I know the concepts of union, intersection, induction, transfinite induction, power sets, ordinals, and basic notions about cardinals.

In first class we studied about first ten axioms. I am supposed to do the exercises of chapter one. My problem is, that, the statements look too obvious to prove. For example:

> **Exercise 1.1:** Verify (1.1): Axiom of extensionality: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same elements, then, $X = Y$.

My answer: $a \in X \Rightarrow a \in Y$ and $a \in Y \Rightarrow a \in X$ Therfore $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$ therfore $X = Y$.

Is this ok?

> **Exercise 1.2:** There is no set $X$ such that $P(X) \subset X$

I know that $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$  but I guess I can't use that? So, what can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the (1.1) referenced in that problem is the one in the section "Pairing." It doesn't make sense to ask you to verify an axiom, and the "Pairing" section doesn't prove the statement (1.1) that $$(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\land b=d$$

For the second one, you get the Russell paradox if $\mathcal P(X)\subset X$. Define $V=\{U\in\mathcal P(X)\mid U\notin U\}$.  $V$ is a  subset of $\mathcal P(X)$. If $\mathcal P(X)\subset X$, then we also have $V\subset X$, and hence $V\in P(X)$. Is $V\in V$?

Comment: This indeed was confusing. Thank you!